# Predict with H2O MOJO Model using hex.genmodel API

Tags: python, pyspark, h2o, py4j

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can load a saved H2O MOJO model and use it on a Spark DataFrame without needing Sparkling Water. The approach I am trying to use is to load up a `h2o-genmodel.jar` file when Spark starts up, and then use then use PySpark's `Py4J` interface to access it. My concrete question will be about how access the values generated by the `py4j.java_gateway` objects.

Below is a minimal example:

#### Train model

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

h2o.init()

features = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,3),columns=list('ABC'))
target = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(["cat","dog","cat","dog","cat","dog"]), columns=["target"])
df = pd.concat([features, target], axis=1)
df_h2o = h2o.H2OFrame(df)

rf = H2ORandomForestEstimator()
rf.train(["A","B","C"],"target",training_frame=df_h2o, validation_frame=df_h2o)
```

#### Save MOJO

```
model_path = rf.download_mojo(path="./mojo/", get_genmodel_jar=True)
print(model_path)
```

#### Load MOJO

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", "/home/ec2-user/Notebooks/mojo/h2o-genmodel.jar").getOrCreate()

MojoModel = spark._jvm.hex.genmodel.MojoModel
EasyPredictModelWrapper = spark._jvm.hex.genmodel.easy.EasyPredictModelWrapper
RowData = spark._jvm.hex.genmodel.easy.RowData

mojo = MojoModel.load(model_path)
easy_model = EasyPredictModelWrapper(mojo)
```

#### Predict on a single row of data

```
r = RowData()
r.put("A", -0.631123)
r.put("B", 0.711463)
r.put("C", -1.332257)

score = easy_model.predictBinomial(r).classProbabilities
```

So, that far I have been able to get. Where I am having trouble is that I find it difficult to inpect what `score` is giving back to me. `print(score)` yields the following: `<py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember at 0x7fb2e09b4e80>`. Presumably there must be a way to the actual generated values from this object, but how would I do that?

Comment: Hi, 
 PySparkling API has support for doing predictions directly without the need of touching Py4J directly. Please see our tests here https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/py/tests/tests_unit_mojo_predictions.py

Comment: Yeah, I actually ran into this yesterday and it does solve my problem quite neatly. I was only looking at the Py4J approach because I wanted to avoid being forced to start a PySparkling session in order to perform prediction. Anyway, I also learnt that the approach I decribed won't work. You would need to wrap the prediction block into a `predict` function and then apply `spark_df.map(predict)` - this won't work since there's no way to get these functions on the executors (Py4J only on driver) and they cannot simply be serialized. If you rewrote the above in Scala or Java it would work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the returned object [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/easy/prediction/BinomialModelPrediction.java). 
`classProbabilities` is a [Java array](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-genmodel/src/main/java/hex/genmodel/easy/prediction/BinomialModelPrediction.java#L33) and Java arrays do not have the `toString` method, which is why your print statement is returning something non-human-readable.

One way to access this value would be to use [py4j](https://www.py4j.org/advanced_topics.html)

for example this should work:

```
for i in easy_model.predictBinomial(r).classProbabilities:
...     print(i)
```

or you can covert it to a list.